# Among the following sets, which are open?

Tags: complex-analysis

Given $U$, an open subset of $\mathbb C$ such that $0\in U$, the question was to select the correct options among the following.

(A) $\{e^z:z\in U\}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb C$

(B) $\{\mid e^z\mid:z\in U\}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R$

(C) $\{\sin z:z\in U\}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb C$

(D) $\{\mid \sin z\mid:z\in U\}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R$.

By Open mapping theorem, we can conclude (A) and (C) are correct, but I am not sure about other two.

A little thought about option (B) is that  $\{\mid e^z\mid:z\in U\}=\{e^x:x\in \pi_x(U)\}$ and I guess $\pi_x(U)$ is open. But not sure how to proceed from here and also how to use given info that $0\in U$.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you check that (D) is correctly cited from your source? It differs from (B) in asking about openness in $\mathbb C$ vs. $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I don't know what "open mapping theorem"  you have in mind, but the [usual theorem known by that name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(functional_analysis)) doesn't apply here.

Comment: $|\sin z|$ has a minimum at $0$ so that's why D is not correct (so not open as subset of the reals as otherwise trivially not open as plane set); on the other hand $|e^z|=e^x, z=x+iy$ so B is indeed correct as the exponential is open on the reals

Comment: @Ingix Yes.. it is $\mathbb{R}$ there.. I have edited

Comment: @RobArthan I was using Open mapping theorem of Complex analysis

Comment: @RobArthan OP means this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(A) and (C) are correct as a direct consequence of Open mapping theorem. Option (B) is the interval $(0,|L|)$ where $L\in\mathbb C$ is attained at some point in the boundary $\partial U$ of $U$. Option (D) must be false as it is an interval $[0,|L|)$.